# Adding Percentage sign to dataframe in scala and writing to excel

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to write data frame to excel using scala.

```
    val noErrors = 20000
    val total = 1000
    val emails = Seq(
      (1, "first", noErrors/100),
      (2, "SPAM SPAM spam", total),
      (3, "Hello, We'd like to", noErrors)
    ).toDF("id", "text","text2")
      .withColumn("text2",
        when($"text2" === lit(-1.0), lit(null)  )
          .otherwise(round($"text2", 1)))
      .orderBy($"id".asc)
      .drop("id")
    emails.show()
```

I am trying to add a % sign to "noErrors/100". Without any conditions, it works fine, but when I add the condition column it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val noErrors = 20000
    val total = 1000
    val emails = Seq(
      (1, "first", noErrors/100),
      (2, "SPAM SPAM spam", total),
      (3, "Hello, We'd like to", noErrors)
    ).toDF("id", "text","text2")
      .withColumn("text2",
        when($"text2" === lit(-1.0), lit(null)  )
          .otherwise(round($"text2", 1)))
      .orderBy($"id".asc)
      .drop("id")

val df = emails.withColumn("text2", when(col("text") === "first","200%") )
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|               text|text2|
+-------------------+-----+
|              first| 200%|
|     SPAM SPAM spam| null|
|Hello, We'd like to| null|
+-------------------+-----+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
noErrors: Int = 20000
total: Int = 1000
emails: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [text: string, text2: int]
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [text: string, text2: string]
```

Is this what you wanted?